# Before I used to meaning?

Tags: used-to

I recently heard this:

Before I used to do *something*, all I cared about was *something else*.

And she meant that she still does *something* and before starting it, all she cared about was *something else*.

And this meaning is not what *used to* means.

Because it's supposed to mean that she was doing *something* in the past but not now.

I couldn't find any grammars that explains this *before + used to*. Can anyone explain?

Comment: *Used to* means she did it in the past, not now. Both things happened in the past, one before the other.

Comment: It used to be that a pogo stick was used to get kids used to doing acrobatics.

Comment: 'Used to' is past in itself. Thus, 'before' may be avoided, if not for emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

> "I used to run marathons" means that during a period (or periods) earlier than now I ran marathons.
>
> "Before I used to run marathons" refers to a period before the start of the period of marathon running.
>
> "Before I used to run marathons, I was lazy and inactive".

Similarly:

> "I used to be a lawyer" means that during a period (or periods) earlier than now I was a lawyer.
>
> "Before I used to be a lawyer, I was a builder" may be part of a narrative such as
> "Before I used to be a lawyer, I was a builder. Now I am retired." In this case too, the lawyer period follows the builder period and the lawyer period ended before now.

Finally:

> If the lawyer period continued until now, it would be more usual to omit the *used to* and to say something like "Before I became a lawyer, I was a builder"